# Reto en PHP que requiere ayuda

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa que imprima números del 1 al 100. En los múltiplos de 3, el programa debe imprimir "pizza". En los múltiplos de 5, debe imprimir "pancake". Y en los múltiplos comunes debe imprimir "pizzapancake". La dificultad esta en que solo se permite el uso de UN solo if, sin else, sin else if, sin switch, sin ternarias. Debe estar escrito en PHP.

Acá dejo mi código

```
       <?php

    class printCondition
    {
        public $message = "";
        public $val = "";
        public function compare($mult, $num, $message){
            $result = $num/$mult;
            $this->val = $num;
            if(is_int($result) ){
                $this->val ="";
                $this->message .= $message;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($x=1; $x<=100 ; $x++ ){
        $obj = new printCondition();
        $obj->compare(3, $x, "pizza");
        $obj->compare(5, $x, "pancake");
        print $obj->message;
        print $obj->val;
        print "<br>";
    }



    ?>
```

Casi funcionó para mí, excepro que cuando imprimia lso multiplos de 3 se imprimia tambien el numero  y no debe ser asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene algun consejo aobre como puedo cumplir mi objetivo estaria muy agradecido. Soy nuevo en PHP y no estoy al tanto de librerias u otras formas de trabajar con clases y herramientas que puedan funcionar. Cualquier consejo es bienvenido.

Comment: El planteamiento de la pregunta es confuso. ¿Se deben imprimir TODOS los números del 1 al 100 o no? Creo que el problema se resolvería simplemente cambiando el orden de impresión así: `print $x;
        print $obj->message; print "<br>";`Nótese que se imprime `$x`, realmente no veo qué sentido tiene aquí crear una instancia de la clase cada vez dentro del bucle. Estás creando CIEN instancias de clase prácticamente para nada, con una sola instancia podrías comparar cada vez, sin concatenar el mensaje. Puede que la clase sobre aquí, depende del requerimiento del ejercicio.

Comment: Se deben imprimir los números que NO sean ni múltiplo de 3, ni múltiplo de 5 ni múltiplos de ambos. En la salida de información puedes ver que donde dice "pizza" hay un número a la derecha, No debería estar ahí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema principal es que muchas veces la condición se cumplirá dos veces y en esos casos no será tan fácil evitar que el número no se muestre.

Con este código podrás resolverlo, respetando las restricciones que expones en el enunciado de la pregunta.

He explicado todo en comentarios in situ, si hay alguna duda me lo dices en comentarios.

El código queda más simple y más portable ... se ve más largo por los comentarios que he puesto :)

```
 class printCondition
    {
         /*
             Un único objeto que sería un array llamado $mData
             para guardar, sea el número, sea la cadena que corresponda
         */
         public $mData=array();
         /*
             La función recibirá un array $mPairs
             con los múltiplos a buscar y con la cadena respectiva... optimización
         */
         public function compare($mPairs, $num){
             /*
                 Inicialmente el valor de $mData será cada valor de $num
             */
             $this->mData[$num]=$num;
             /*
                 Buscamos el array de múltiplos que se requiera
             */
             foreach ($mPairs as $k=>$v){
                if(is_int($num/$k)){
                    /*
                        Si la condición se cumple, quitamos el valor de $num
                        y lo cambiamos por la cadena, que estaría en $v
                        en sucesivas iteracciones se agregará la otra parte
                        de la cadena si fuera preciso
                    */
                    $this->mData[$num]=str_replace($num,"",$this->mData[$num]);
                    $this->mData[$num].=$v;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    /*
        OJO aquí a varias cosas:
        1.  Estamos ante un código optimizado, pues
            creamos una instancia del objeto, no CIEN instancias
        2.  Estamos ante un código portable, y simplificado
            pasando un array con los valores cuyos múltiplos queremos
            así como con las cadenas de reemplazo
        3.  Liberamos al objeto de propiedades innecesarias
            para este caso. Todo se obtendrá desde la propiedad mData
    */
    $obj = new printCondition();

    for ($x=1; $x<=100 ; $x++ ){
        /*
            Cambia la forma de pasar los datos al objeto
            y el tipo de dato que se pasa
        */
        $obj->compare([3=>"pizza",5=>"pancake"], $x);
        print $obj->mData[$x];
        print PHP_EOL;
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
1
2
pizza
4
pancake
pizza
7
8
pizza
pancake
11
pizza
13
14
pizzapancake
16
17
pizza
19
pancake
pizza
22
23
pizza
pancake
26
pizza
28
29
pizzapancake
31
32
pizza
34
pancake
pizza
37
38
pizza
pancake
41
pizza
43
44
pizzapancake
46
47
pizza
49
pancake
pizza
52
53
pizza
pancake
56
pizza
58
59
pizzapancake
61
62
pizza
64
pancake
pizza
67
68
pizza
pancake
71
pizza
73
74
pizzapancake
76
77
pizza
79
pancake
pizza
82
83
pizza
pancake
86
pizza
88
89
pizzapancake
91
92
pizza
94
pancake
pizza
97
98
pizza
pancake
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @lufesome me alegro. Revisa la respuesta editada, he logrado simplificar aún más, pasando un sólo array asociativo de este modo: `[3=>"pizza",5=>"pancake"]` ahí tendríamos al múltiplo a buscar y la cadena a mostrar. Así queda mucho mejor. He editado la respuesta para agregar esa optimización suplementaria. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya han dado una buena respuesta, dejo aquí una versión que no usa ningún if, solo algo parecido a las tablas de verdad:

```
<?php

    function compare($tablaComida, $mult, $num, $message){
        $valor = $tablaComida[$mult][$num % $mult];
        $esPalabra = $valor !== "";
        print $valor;
        return $esPalabra;
    }

    $tablaComida = array();
    $tablaComida[3] = array("pizza", "", "");
    $tablaComida[5] = array("pancake", "", "", "", "");

    for ($x=1; $x <= 100 ; $x++ ){
        $esPalabra = 0;
        $esPalabra |= compare($tablaComida, 3, $x, "pizza");
        $esPalabra |= compare($tablaComida, 5, $x, "pancake");
        $tablaNumeros = [$x, ""];
        print $tablaNumeros[$esPalabra];
        print "\n";
    }
```

Tenemos estas dos tablas, en la primera, tablaComida, guardamos el valor que tiene que imprimirse en función de si el número es divisible por 3 y por 5.

Por ejemplo:

- si dividimos entre 3 y el resto es 0 se tiene que escribir "pizza"
- si dividimos entre 3 y el resto es 1 se tiene que escribir ""
- si dividimos entre 3 y el resto es 2 se tiene que escribir ""

La otra tabla (tablaNumeros) es para ver si imprimimos el número o no. Se supone que el número hay que imprimirlo solo si no se ha escrito ninguna palabra. Por lo que lo que la tabla significa que si no hay palabras (0) se ecriba el número y si hay palabras (1) se escriba "".

Para ver si ha habido palabras hay que ir haciendo ors de las llamadas a compare, para que en cuanto se encuentre una palabra, se ponga a 1. Si no se ha encontrado se queda en 0.

Comment: Veo dos problemas ahí: 1º estaríamos creando `N` instancias del objeto sin demasiada necesidad; 2º si hiciera falta buscar múltiplos de `N` números habría que agregar esas `N` condiciones a mano en la clase. En mi caso, si se quisiera también los múltimplos de `2` sólo habría que pasar esto: `[3=>"pizza",5=>"pancake", 2=>"duo"]` y listo, el método queda intacto.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, he simplificado el tema de crear ese objeto que realmente no sirve para nada. Con el cambio si quisiese hacer el múltiplo de 2, sería algo así: `$tablaComidas[2] = array("duo", ""):`

Answer (score 0):

Ya aceptaste una respuesta, pero otra forma corta y eficiente que se me ocurre, sería con una variable `$val` que su valor se va actualizando en un `for` a medida que:

> `$val` = 'pizza' si `($num % $cond1 == 0)`, de lo contrario el valor de `$num;`
> `$val` = 'pancake' si `($num % $cond2 == 0)`, de lo contrario el valor actual de `$val`
> Imprime 'pizzapancake' si `($num % $cond3 == 0)`, caso contrario el valor actual de `$val`

El código en cuestión quedará así:

```
<?php
function compare($num, $cond, $last_val, $str) {
    if($num % $cond == 0) {
        return $str;
    }
    return $last_val;
}

for($num=1; $num<=100; $num++) {
    $val = compare($num, 3, $num, 'pizza');
    $val = compare($num, 5, $val, 'pancake');
    print compare($num, 3*5, $val, 'pizzapancake') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alternativas

`for` `foreach` `if`

```php
<?php
$reemplazos = [ 3 => 'pizza', 5 => 'pancake' ];
for ( $numero = 1; 100 >= $numero; $numero++ ){
  $imprime = $numero;
  foreach( $reemplazos as $divisor => $palabra ){
    if ( 0 == $numero % $divisor ) {
      $imprime = str_replace( $numero, '', $imprime ) . $palabra . ' ';
    }
  }
  echo $imprime . PHP_EOL;
}
```

`range` `array_map` `foreach` `if`

```php
$reemplazos = [ 3 => 'pizza', 5 => 'pancake' ];
$numeros = range( 1, 100 );
$imprime = array_map( function ( $numero ) use ( $reemplazos ){
  $linea = $numero;
  foreach( $reemplazos as $divisor => $palabra ){
    if ( 0 == $numero % $divisor ) {
      $linea = str_replace( $numero, '', $linea ) . $palabra . ' ';
    }
  }
  return $linea;
}
, $numeros );

foreach( $imprime as $linea ){ 
  echo $linea . PHP_EOL;
};
```

`foreach` `range` `if`

```php
function numeros(){
  yield from range( 1, 100 );
}

function reemplazos(){
  yield from [ 3 => 'pizza', 5 => 'pancake'];
}

function numerosopalabras() {
  foreach ( numeros() as $numero ){
    $imprime = $numero;
    foreach( reemplazos() as $divisor => $palabra ){
      if ( 0 == $numero % $divisor ) {
        $imprime = str_replace( $numero, '', $imprime ) . $palabra . ' ';
      }
    }
    yield $imprime;
  }
}

foreach( numerosopalabras() as $linea ){ 
  echo $linea . PHP_EOL;
};
```